# How to efficiently convert a data frame to a list of lists of arbitrary length?

Tags: r

I am trying to reshape a data frame for more efficient storage and retrieval. Each row contains a "parent" (key) value, which is not unique between rows, and a child value (actually, a set of 3 attributes -- 1 character and 2 numeric). I want to transform this data frame into a list that has just one top-level entry for each unique parent key, and a number of sub-lists as determined by the number of children associate with the parent. Here are some sample data:

```
pcm <- data.frame(parent = c("middle", "middle", "might", "might", 
                     "might", "million", "million", "millions"),
              child = c("of", "school", "be", "have", "not", "in", 
                     "to", "of"),
              count = c(476, 165, 1183, 619, 321, 490, 190, 269))
```

The output for this should be a list with 4 top-level elements (named `"middle", "might", "million", "millions"`), and varying numbers of sub-lists with named members `$child` and `$count` (e.g. `lookup4[["middle"]]` contains sub-lists `$children[[1]]$child` = `"of"`, `$count` = `476` and `$children[[2]]$child` = `"school"`, `$count` = `165`).

The code below works, but is extremely slow (several hours on a 300,000-row data frame using 8 GB RAM). I have imposed a limit of 6 on the number of children in the output data, but it doesn't seem to have made a big difference.

```
lookup4 <- list()
parents <- unique(pcm$parent)
n.parents <- length(parents)
for (i in 1:n.parents) {
    words <- pcm$child[pcm$parent == parents[i]]
    counts <- pcm$count[pcm$parent == parents[i]]
    probs <- pcm$prob[pcm$parent == parents[i]]
    n.children <- min(c(NROW(words), 6)
    ngram.tail <- list()
    for (k in 1:n.children) {
        ngram.tail[[k]] <- list(word = words[k], 
        count = counts[k], 
        prob = probs[k])
    }
    lookup4[[parents[i]]] <- list(children = ngram.tail)
}
```

Could I speed it up by eliminating the 'for' loop? If so, how would I code the transformation?

Comment: What is `pcm`?  Please show a small reproducible example and exxpected output

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to post a question that is recommended

Comment: `split(pcm[,c("child","count","prob")],pcm$parent)` should be the first step. Next, what's the reason of having many sublists instead of a `data.frame` with multiple rows? I guess that the output of `split(...)` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, akrun. I have added some data.

Comment: Thanks, nicola. The length of each sublist can vary, plus I want to be able to add more elements on-the-fly, so I don't think I should be using data frames. There are 600k rows in the actual `pcm` input data frame, but my reformation of the data results in just 39k rows. (It's just so dang slow to rebuild it!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I suppose that the dataframe is called `parents`:

```
parents.list <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(parents)))
```

If you want the row names of parents to be the names of the list:

```
parents.list <- setNames(split(parents, seq(nrow(parents))), rownames(parents))
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe, but these don't do what I want. The name of each top-level list element should be a unique value of `parents`. I'll put up some example data shortly.